# OpenFire: SHA-1 passwords without blowfish encryption

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I want to be able to create users that have a straight up SHA-1 password.  No Blowfish, nothing special, just plain old vanilla SHA-1.  The only way I have been able to accomplish this so far has been to extend DefaultUserProvider and override the createUser, making the following change:

```
if (!usePlainPassword) {
    try {
        encryptedPassword = StringUtils.hash(password.getBytes(),"SHA-1");
        // encryptedPassword = AuthFactory.encryptPassword(password);
        // Set password to null so that it's inserted that way.
        password = null;
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException uoe) {
        // Encrypting the password may have failed if in setup mode.
        // Therefore, use the plain password.
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thoughts? Suggestions?

(The reason for this "requirement" is that I am trying to access `ofUser` table via mod_auth_mysql so that I can have a "single sign on" solution for all the different areas of my project such as Subversion.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my initial solution (provided in the question) is the only way to accomplish this functionality.  I have conversed with others on the openfire support forum and they concur.

Comment: It seems a bit late to ask this, but i'll give it a shot. Could you provide a more thorough steps on how to accomplish this? did you re-build openfire from source or ....?

Comment: It has been quite a while since I was working on that... but if I remember correctly, I ultimately ended up doing something like this http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html At the time, I don't believe this level of integration was possible out of the box... might be now... would be interested to know if it works for you.

Comment: even i am having problem with that. I haven't got any luck since last week.

Comment: @JeremyRIrawan : I am trying to do the same . If it was resolved at your end then can you please share the details with me too . I really need them .

Comment: @abrightwell, Do you have a link to the thread whereby "they concur" that this is the only solution?

Comment: @Pacerier, [Here](https://vanity-igniterealtime.jiveon.com/message/205360#205360) is the thread.  I hope it helps add to the conversation.  Though, it has been almost four years since the original post so I am not certain how relevant it is anymore.